# В каких случаях стоит, а в каких - нет, использовать TDD? Чем опасно его не использовать?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, веб-программирование, test-driven-development

Никак не могу понять, как TDD сумел обрести такую популярность. Почему? Потому что я считаю это максимально иррациональным подходом к разработке:

- Ты должен написать тест, который заведомо провалится.
  *Трата времени*. Ты не написал ни одной строчки кода, зато написал 20 строк кода, чтобы убедиться в том, что то, чего ты **не** написал, не работает.
- Ты должен написать тест, который реализует твои мысли относительно того, как это должно работать.
  *Трата времени.* За то время, пока ты реализовывал свои мысли в строках *теста*, ты мог реализовать свои мысли строками *кода*.
- Ты должен написать код так, чтобы он прошел написанный тест.
  А в это время ты уже мог заниматься *рефакторингом* написанного кода.
- Рефакторинг.

---

Еще одна особенность. Как мы знаем, веб-разработка предполагает разработку того, с чем конечный пользователь будет взаимодействовать через браузер. Подход TDD предполагает максимальное абстрагирование от браузера и использование для проверки работоспособности кода только командную строку. Чувствуете этот запах? Так пахнет логика.

---

Чтобы мои слова не звучали необоснованно, я приведу вам пример того, как я пытался освоить данную ветвь.

Изначально я знал, что люди с нелюбовью относятся к имеющемуся в rails стандартному test-фреймворку. И я также прекрасно знал, что подавляющее большинство предпочитает ему использование Rspec.

Первым делом я, конечно же, решил ознакомиться с документацией по Rspec. По первой же ссылке в гугле я попал на [эту страницу](http://rspec.info/). Красивый landing-page с кучей видео разряда ни о чем. Окей, почитаю [документацию](http://rspec.info/documentation/), решил я. Абсолютно ничего дельного эта страница мне не принесла. Лишь внизу красовалась [ссылка](https://relishapp.com/rspec) на какой-то Relish. Что это такое и каким боком оно относится к Rspec - непонятно. Ладно, переходим.
Только оттуда с непримечательной ссылки Rspec-core (догадайся 2) я попал на нечто, что хоть как-то похоже на то, что я ищу. Какие-то примеры кода. Да, сразу код. Не понятно, как установить, какая структура должна быть у папок, как нужно именовать файлы, как запускать - ничего.

Спустя день, перелопатив кучу инфы по этому поводу, я узнал, куда стоит класть файлы, как именовать папки, что require-ить, какие методы использовать (базу). Помогли мне в этом довольно полезные скринкасты (на которых, кстати говоря, было полностью разработано приложение без использования тестов, а тесты писались "в обучающих нас целях", когда все уже заведомо работало так, как надо, и в данном случае тесты подгонялись под код, а не наоборот (как это предполагает TDD), что еще раз доказывает нам ненадобность использования оного). Не было ни какой конкретной инфы (в виде гайда, как это сделано в случае rails, или хотя бы общей спарвки) ни на хабре, ни на railscasts (даже с pro-подпиской), на которых R. Bates в своей привычной манере "проскакал" по верхам, показав типичный пример из ряда "сделайте так-то, у меня получилось так-то, на это до свидания".

Садимся писать. Создаем приложение, устанавливаем необходимые гемы, пишем. Решил я начать по-порядку. Роутинг. Написал тесты, которые должны были заведомо провалиться. Провалились не тесты, а сам Rspec. Оказалось, ошибка синтаксиса (правильно, я же еще должен знать, **как** писать). Тратим время на поиск примеров. Реализуем. Тесты провалились. Реализовываем код (а что там реализовывать? Написал необходимые мне пути). Тесты прошли. На все про все у меня ушло около 3-х часов. За это время я бы успел реализовать не только логику routing'а, но и логику модели и отчасти каких-то контроллеров.

Решил заняться написанием контроллеров. Опять уперся в банальное незнание и неумение пользоваться новым инструментом. Как человек наученный каким-то опытом, не стал проклинать в этом всех и вся, а просто полез в документацию. Окей, гугл, "rspec controller". [Это все, что нам предоставляет, насколько я понял, официальная документация](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs). Опять же этот Relish. На этом этапе я матюкнулся, послал все к чертям и решил немного отдохнуть. Теперь, отдухнув, пишу сюда. И нет, пишу я не с целью выговориться или в очередной раз, но уже на публику, проклясть этот TDD, а разобраться.

Да, даже несмотря на все мои неудачи, я хочу разобраться, во-первых, в том, почему же этот TDD так популярен? Почему все "настоятельно рекомендуют закрыть браузер и написать парочку тестов", когда можно спокойно (и даже более полезно для себя с точки зрения психики) обойтись простым визитом на `localhost:3000`? Что движет всеми теми, кто так усердно (если такие вообще есть, и это не просто показуха) использует TDD? И самое главное: в чем опасность отказа от этого подхода? Может ли отказ как-то сказаться на твоем резюме или в поиске работы?

Если есть действительно весомые аргументы против моей точки зрения, то прошу подкрепить свой ответ ссылками на обучающие материалы по этой теме (желательно от и до, подкрепленные real-life примерами и охватывающие хотя бы половину из того, с чем можно столкнуться при реальном использовании).

Спасибо тем, кто осилил. Заранее извиняюсь, если это оскорбило чьи-то чувства. Предполагается, что все, что написано выше - ИМХО.

Comment: На всякий случай повторюсь. **Цель - научиться, если необходимо или получить подтверждение того, что не необходимо**, а не устроить холивар и распри из за того, что ваше мнение не совпадает с моим.

Comment: Вопросы формата "как вы относитесь" на StackOverflow неуместны, поскольку не предполагают объективного ответа и превращаются в опросники мнений.

Comment: @D-side Как правильно задать, чтобы не нарушать правила сообщества?

Comment: Никак. Это тема для обсуждения, а не вопрос, и не вписывается в формат Q&A StackOverflow. Для обсуждения разве что чат можно создать.

Comment: @D-side не соглашусь с вами. Вопрос (и не один) был конкретно поставлен. Вся остальная вода - чтобы подкрепить свое мнение и не казаться голословным.

Comment: То, что "(и не один)", тем хуже. А то, что вопрос конкретно поставлен, не означает, что на него можно дать объективный ответ. Именно поэтому он (как в данном случае) является темой для обсуждения.

Comment: @D-side Я думаю, на мой вопрос можно дать объективный ответ:  
Чем опасно? - Тем-то.  
Когда можно не использовать? - тогда-то.  
Повлияет ли на поиск работы? - да/нет.  
Плюс привести ссылки (как я и просил) для изучения, если вы считаете, что потребность действительно есть.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40139/discussion-between-d-side-and--).

Comment: если ваш код по-разному работает через браузер и командную строку, то ха-ха ха-ха

Comment: @Etki Разве я где-то такое сказал?

Comment: *Подход TDD предполагает максимальное абстрагирование от браузера и использование для проверки работоспособности кода только командную строку. Чувствуете этот запах?* - если нет разницы, откуда вызывать, то имеет ли смысл этот пассаж?

Comment: @Etki именно в этом и заключается суть вопроса. Если нет смысла в этом "пассаже", то почему же он тогда так популярен?

Comment: Если в этом пассаже нет смысла, то ничего не препятствует его использованию, нет?

Comment: @Etki препятствует отсутствие смысла.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь есть три составляющие:

Во-первых, сами тесты.
Они нужны, в первую очередь, чтобы при дальнейшем изменении приложения не ломался старый функционал. Понятно, что, если приложение достаточно маленькое, быстрее и приятнее прокликать всё руками. Но с каждой новой фичой такое прокликивание будет занимать всё больше времени. К тому же, какие-то кейсы могут быть забыты. Автотесты же помогают прогнать тесты быстро и минимизировать человеческий фактор. В итоге, появляется возможность использовать [CI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). RSpec, в основном, подразумевает написание модульных тестов. Однако можно использовать, например [Cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber) - тесты больше похожи на привычное "прокликать". Но, при этом, сами сценарии тестов становятся сложнее, т.к. сразу нужно проверить гораздо больше кейсов.

Во-вторых, TDD.
Пожалуй, в рамках TDD тесты понятнее будет называть спецификациями (specifications, specs - в RSpec). По сути, это текст задания, написанный в понятном для интерпретатора виде. На сколько написание спецификаций до кода себя оправдывает - один из холиваров. В любом случае, автотесты нужны. А в какой момент их писать - решать тебе.

Лично мне было сложно писать "test first" (да и "last") до знакомства с принципами SOLID. Но, теперь, как сайд-эффект, мне легче проектировать архитектуру классов. Специфика RSspec такова, что легче тестировать солидные классы. (Спеки для несолидных получаются длинные, с кучей стабов и моков.). Судя по [статье](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B8.D0.BC.D1.83.D1.89.D0.B5.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.B0) в вики, не я один отметил этот эффект:

> Разработка через тестирование предлагает больше, чем просто проверку корректности, она также влияет на дизайн программы.
>
> Разработка через тестирование способствует более модульному, гибкому и расширяемому коду.

В-третьих, RSpec. Как я уже говорил, это не единственный фреймворк для написание тестов. На сколько я понял, основные проблемы возникли именно из-за его незнания. Но это не делает его "плохим". Писать быстро на незнакомом фреймворке вряд ли получится хоть у кого-то. Да, написание тестов, как и любого другого кода, занимает дополнительное время. Но обычно, всё же, это не 3 часа вместо 15 минут. В твоём же случае, это были  затраты на обучение а не написание.

Кстати, я в первый раз вижу, чтобы тестировали роуты. Обычно не требуется покрытие всего кода тестами. Корректность части компонентов (например тех же роутов) будет очевидна из корректности остальных компонентов.

Ну и на практике, TDD хорошо подходит для крупных проектов, в которых проектирование на должном уровне. Для стартапов, функционал которых не очень велик, зато очень часты изменения - может быть излишним. Для лендингов, весь бэкенд сводится к отправки email с введённым пользователем телефоном - тоже.

Comment: Развернуто, большая часть понятна, благодарю. Под вопросом остался только  SOLID. Что это и с чем его есть?

Comment: Это [набор рекомендаций](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) к написанию кода, следование которому позволяет упростить поддержку / доработку / модификацию приложения.

Comment: Спасибо. Не совсем про тестирование, насколько я понял по вашему описанию, но все же почитаю.

Comment: @МатвейМамонов дело в том, что тестируемость связана с дизайном кода. Код, который хорошо спроектирован, легко тестировать. И наоборот, код, который имеет плохой дизайн, тестировать очень сложно. SOLID -- это о том, как делать хороший дизайн. При его применении написание тестов почти автоматически становится значительно более легким делом.

Comment: @andreycha при хорошем коде отпадает необходимость тестирования как такового. Плюс тестами невозможно покрыть 100% кода и на 100% быть уверенным в правильности поведения. Поэтому для себя я этот вопрос уже давно закрыл и решил, что тестировать буду только ту логику, которая довольно сложная и добавляется в модель при расширении (максимум - в контроллер) с целью того, чтобы существующая не поломалась. Потому как тестировать вьюхи и им подобное - это полный д-зм.

Comment: @МатвейМамонов *"при хорошем коде отпадает необходимость тестирования как такового"* -- понятно :).

Answer (score 2):

Надо понимать на что и как писать тесты, в каждом проекте может быть очень важный участок, внесение изменений в который очень критично - например модуль для подсчета денежной информации, так и участок менее важный - например ui админки сайта.

А так, навскидку:

Поддерживаемость - Тесты нужны, например, если вы собираетесь без боли рефакторить код, потом, через год, или не вы.

Модульность, принцип единой ответственности - TDD вынуждает разработчика писать чище и проще, заранее придумывать апи, держать цикломатическую сложность в тонусе.

Comment: > Надо понимать на что и как писать тесты, в каждом проекте может быть очень важный участок, внесение изменений в который очень критично - например модуль для подсчета денежной информации, так и участок менее важный - например ui админки сайта. С админкой понятно. С подсчетом денег - тоже. Непонятно про внесение изменений. Вы хотите сказать, что писать тест стоит только в том случае, если в участок кода, за который ответственен этот тест, будут точно вносится изменения?

Comment: > Поддерживаемость - Тесты нужны, например, если вы собираетесь без боли рефакторить код, потом, через год, или не вы. Тесты стоит использовать с расчетом на то, что код будет изменять другой разраб? Если заранее достоверно известно, что код буду писать только я - то и тесты можно не писать?
> Модульность, принцип единой ответственности - TDD вынуждает разработчика писать чище и проще, заранее придумывать апи, держать цикломатическую сложность в тонусе.
Полностью не согласен про чистый код. Аргументируйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Я не сказал что без тестов код ужасен, я сказал что TDD вынуждает писать чище

Comment: В большом проекте - тесты это добро, они помогают другим разработчикам больше понять о коде, который вы напишете. При написании тестов вы заметите, что некоторые решения - не удобно тестировать а некоторые удобно. Обычно модуль, который аккуратно использует зависимости - удобно тестировать, рефакторить (поддерживать), переиспользовать в другом проекте, выделить в независимый проект, много плюсов, но за это вы платите, иногда это трата а иногда - инвестиция. решать вам

Comment: Аргументируйте, я же прошу. Я выдвигаю тезис - разработка оканчивается на том моменте, когда код "подогнан" под тест - соответственно он просто выполняет свою функцию и не обязательно выгладит красиво. Те же самые роуты я написал с тестированием точно так же, как и написал бы без тестов.

Comment: Вы один работаете над проектом?

Comment: Да, один. Не приходилось работать в команде. И я не думаю, что работа в одиночку мешает писать чистый код.

Comment: Вы художник - вам решать какой вам нужен код и какие тесты

Comment: Но мой вам совет, если вы столкнетесь с разработкой модуля, где сразу видно какие должны быть входные данные а какие выходные - начните с написания теста, скорее всего вам понравится =)

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Только я не совсем понял: он относится к Rails?
> Вы художник - вам решать какой вам нужен код и какие тесты  
Спасибо, конечно, но вопрос как раз и состоял в том, стоит их использовать, или нет.

Comment: Это вы должны решить сами, исходя из ваших требований. Тесты это время, если они не принесут пользы - это траты, а если принесут - инвестиции в будущее. как то так, это никак не отностится к rails, коего я в глаза не видел, это общий принцип при разработке по, язык и платформа не имеет значения.

Comment: Теперь понятно.

Comment: Пару лет назад отсутствие сбойного теста на разрыв соединения в одной видеосистеме стоило мне бессонной ночи. и это еще цветочки, бывает хуже

Comment: Но ведь получается же, что вы потом писали писали тест, основываясь на уже имеющемся коде (вы ведь писали?), и тогда это нельзя считать TDD.

Comment: Изначально модуль был написан не мной, но вносил изменения в него я, и что печально тесты там были, но не полные, что создает иллюзию безопасности

Comment: плохие тесты хуже полного отсутствия оных